# Python - Grandparents methods (genes)

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I'm currently making a simple script that let's me control multiple (32) switches and routers trough a Access server. I already made a class that initiates the serial connection

Anyway, my question is how do I use an inherited method? I have a grandparent Devices that has 2 children(Father) Router and Switches. These 2 children became father to a few children let's keep it simple with SwitchA SwitchB & RouterA. Now in Cisco devices some configurations are 'standard' but not all. Let's say I want to enter "configuration terminal" trough the serial port.

Focus:

```
class Devices(object):
'Grandparent Class for Cisco Devices'

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__a = a

    def enterConfT(self):
        self.__a.send( "\r" )
        self.__a.send("enable\r")
        print("enabled")
        self.__a.send( "config terminal\r" )
        print("Entered global configuration mode.")


class Switches(Devices):
'Switches Parent?'

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_nothing_yet(self):
        pass


class switchA(Switches):
'Catalyst 3850 Teletest'

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
```

In another file I got:

```
y = TClasses.cisco.test.switchA(serial1)
y.enterConfT()
```

this gives the following exception/error(I took out file directories):

```
'switchA' object has no attribute '_Devices__a'
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/sorry_privacy/test.py", line 30, in <module>\n    y.enterConfT()\n', '  File "/sorry_hehe/TClasses.py", line 24, in enterConfT\n    self.__a.send( "\\r" )\n', "AttributeError: 'switchA' object has no attribute '_Devices__a'\n"]
```

I want to be able to keep the variables a and x private while they are pointing to the same object.
What I know from OOP and C++, Minimalise repeated code and I didn't seem to have a problem with grandparent inheritence in C++ but I know Python works differently. I also read a few Q&A but couldn't really understand what they meant. I'm a beginner Python scripter.

Thank you in advance and excuse my english.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. Using super() in the **init** I can initialize from parent.

This was helpfull, as I tend to read very fast and globally.
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php